# Setting several "setValue" at once

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, setvalue

I have some cells (that are non-adjacenet). Each of these has a range name in the form "rLamp*nn*" as below.

```
  ss.getRangeByName("rLamp20").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  ss.getRangeByName("rLamp19").setValue(e.range.getValue());
  ss.getRangeByName("rLamp18").setValue(e.range.getValue());
```

I want to put the same value into several of them at once. (Each of them then has a conditional format which changes the cell colour depending on what was entered into them).

Is there a more efficient way (i.e. quicker) of setting the same value into a group of these cells rather than individual calls like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many of them you could loop `.setValue()` using the *nn* index in the named ranges:

```
var fName = 'rLamp';
var howManyNamedRanges = 20;
// Assuming the first NamedRange is rLamp0
for (var i=0;i<howManyNamedRanges;i++) {
  ss.getRangeByName(fName+i).setValue(e.range.getValue());    
}
```

If the first named ranges is 1 or else you could change it to:

```
var fName = 'rLamp';
var firstNamedRange = 4;
var lastNamedRange = 20;
// Assuming the first NamedRange is rLamp[n]
for (var i=firstNamedRange;i<=lastNamedRange;i++) {
  ss.getRangeByName(fName+i).setValue(e.range.getValue());    
}
```

Comment: Oh I like this, thanks it's a lot neater. Bizarrely though it's not actually any quicker. In my current sheet I have 72 of these 'rlamp' cells and using my original method and k4k4sh1's method takes exactly the same amount of time. But it is neater ... and less code.

Comment: It's not faster because there is not optimization for these calls, they are basically wrappers around API requests, with the API not suppoorting setValues for non continuous ranges.

Comment: Indeed it's not faster, it's just shorter.